# excel 2016 vba user defined function volatile

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

*Reposted on stackoverflow as this question might be a more programming related question*

I am working with two structured table on two worksheets in one workbook.

I am using my UDF in SheetA which takes 3 arguments as string.

The first argument is ID column, the second argument is the first 8 characters on its column header cell, the third argument is the last 8 characters on its column header cell.

The UDF is applied to many other similar cells. The columns will be expanded as time pass by. ID and header cells are all static value. They are not derived from other cells.

The UDF will search TableB by "Application.Match" and draw values from matching rows and columns. If everything is valid, it will return appropriate results.

SheetA: TableA

| ID | 04/07/21 - 10/07/21 | 11/07/21 - 17/07/21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8)) | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21,8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8)) |
| AABBCC | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8)) | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21,8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8)) |

SheetB: TableB

| Date | 123456 | AABBCC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/21 | 5.0 | -- |
| 05/07/21 | -- | 7.5 |
| 06/07/21 | -- | 7.5 |
| 07/07/21 | 8 | -- |
| 08/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 09/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 10/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 11/07/21 | -- | -- |

**My problem is that my UDF is causing time consuming calculation whenever I edit the tables (i.e. volatile) even I'm not editing those three arguments/related cells. Also, UDF recalculate whenever I collapse/expand grouped table columns. I would like to make the UDF recalculate only (when one of the arguments changes) or (if the values in "SumRange" changes). The result should behave somewhat like an index/match formula, when the matching range is updated.**

Here shows the UDF:

```
Function UDF(ID As String, Date1 As String, Date2 As String) As Variant
    TargetTable = "TableB"
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB")

    With WS1
        matchCol = Application.Match(ID, .ListObjects(TargetTable).HeaderRowRange, 0)
        If IsError(matchCol) Then
            UDF = "ID not found"
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        matchRow1 = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(Date1)), .ListObjects(TargetTable).ListColumns("Date").Range, 0)
        matchRow2 = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(Date2)), .ListObjects(TargetTable).ListColumns("Date").Range, 0)
        
        Set SumRange = .Range(.Cells(matchRow1, matchCol), .Cells(matchRow2, matchCol))
        
        Arr = SumRange.Value
        For Each cel In Arr
            If Len(Trim(cel)) > 0 Then
                UDF = Application.Sum(SumRange)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
    
    UDF = ""
End Function
```

Comment: can you post code of your UDF?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have included the code

Comment: "UDF is causing time consuming calculation whenever I edit the tables" - to make sure it's indeed your UDF, could you please insert these two lines at the beginning : `UDF = Application.Worksheetfunction.Now() Exit Function`

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

A volatile UDF is recalculated EVERY time ANY cell changes value or anything else triggers recalculation.

So adding data to a cell causes recalc of the UDF.

As you add, edit, or remove entries to ANY cell, Table cells or not, ALL of your uses of the UDF will recalculate.

Depending upon how many uses you've made of your UDF (and how long each takes to calculate, though that seems unlikely to be long in your described circumstance), you could easily see a noticeable lag even though nothing is wrong.

This is basic to the making of a UDF volatile and is the answer to the question "Why wouldn't I just make every UDF volatile?" Notice the difference between them and an Excel built-in function which Excel properly builds into its calculation tree and only recalcs when it needs done. Unfortunately, there is no middle ground without more VBA work.

Something you could do might be to make it non-volatile and add an ON KEY recalc command for the cell in the row you are editing. That way the edits in a row will force recalc of that row's UDF (but no other) and while you might have 50 columns whose cells do that, it's just 50 recalcs of the one UDF use rather than 50 recalcs of all the UDF's. In a, say, 1,000 or 20,000 row Table, that might make a difference.

The only direct change that matters to your UDF is the ID column cell for the row it is in. If it were ON KEY'd to recalc the UDF cell in the row, that'd do it. Probably. If there were any indirect changes that could occur such as the ID column cell is populated with a formula whose dependents see some value change, the ON KEY approach would not catch the change.

So plusses and minuses. You get to decide how they all add up.

Documentation for the volatility setting for UDF's can be found at:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: Is UDF by default volatile? cause I didn't use application.volatile and I expect it to recalculate only when one of the argument cell changes

Comment: TableB will be updated by another script. I would like the changes from TableB be reflected on TableA by my UDF. Refer to my UDF script, I would like the UDF to recalculate (when the values in "SumRange" changes) or (when one of the three arguments changes). The result should behave somewhat like an index/match formula, when the matching range is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with your UDF, but how you call it.

`=UDF(TableA[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8),RIGHT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8))`

Here `[@[ID]:[ID]]` is incorrect syntax. It evaluates to `[@[ID]]` however it appears as an array. When I changed it to `[@[ID]]`, your UDF stopped behaving as volatile.

Comment: But I need to fill the formula sideways and downwards. I put it that way as absolute reference to a column in a structured table. (https://www.excelcampus.com/tips-shortcuts/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/)

Comment: structured references work as absolute column references, have you tried it with my formula?

Comment: I tried, I cannot drag across columns. The reference lost. The formula in C2 and C3 become:

=UDF([@[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8),RIGHT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8))